# Github Actions failing to install Libv8 gem on ubuntu-18.04.5

Tags: ruby, bundler, v8, github-actions, libv8

We are using Github Actions for our CI setup. all of sudden our Gem installation action stopped working when it is trying to install `mini_racer` gem which depends on `libv8` gem. but when actions try to install and build extentions for this gem it fails there.

here are the configurations:

```
jobs:
  spec:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgresql:
        image: circleci/postgres:11.5-alpine-ram
        ports: ["5432:5432"]
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER:
          POSTGRES_DB:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD:

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Bundler/Gems Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: vendor/bundle
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-bundle-v1-${{ hashFiles('Gemfile.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-bundle-v1-

      - name: Read nvm version
        id: nvmrc
        run: echo ::set-output "name=NODEVERSION::$(cat .nvmrc)"

      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "${{ steps.nvmrc.outputs.NODEVERSION }}"

      - name: Install Gems
        run: |
          gem install --no-document bundler
          bundle config path vendor/bundle
          bundle config set without 'development'
          bundle install --deployment --jobs 2
```

here are the logs:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.6.6/x64/bin/ruby -I
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.6.6/x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20201214-2974-1gm42lz.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
WARNING: Your metrics.cfg file was invalid or nonexistent. A new one will be
created.

________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout
--progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor/_gclient_v8_msyeloop'
in
'/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor'
Cloning into
'/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor/_gclient_v8_msyeloop'...
remote: Sending approximately 777.22 MiB ...Counting objects: 1           
remote: Counting objects: 1166           
remote: Counting objects: 3144        
remote: Counting objects: 7699, done
remote: Finding sources:   2% (1/38)           
remote: Finding sources:   5%
(2/38)           
remote: Finding sources:   7% (3/38)           
remote:
Finding sources:  10% (4/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  13% (5/38)    
remote: Finding sources:  15% (6/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  18%
(7/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  21% (8/38)           
remote:
Finding sources:  23% (9/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  26% (10/38)   
remote: Finding sources:  28% (11/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  31%
(12/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  34% (13/38)           
remote:
Finding sources:  36% (14/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  39% (15/38)  
remote: Finding sources:  42% (16/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  44%
(17/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  47% (18/38)           
remote:
Finding sources:  50% (19/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  52% (20/38)  
remote: Finding sources:  55% (21/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  57%
(22/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  60% (23/38)           
remote:
Finding sources:  63% (24/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  65% (25/38)  
remote: Finding sources:  68% (26/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  71%
(27/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  73% (28/38)           
remote:
Finding sources:  76% (29/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  78% (30/38)  
remote: Finding sources:  81% (31/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  84%
(32/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  86% (33/38)           
remote:
Finding sources:  89% (34/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  92% (35/38)  
remote: Finding sources:  94% (36/38)           
remote: Finding sources:  97%
(37/38)           
remote: Finding sources: 100% (38/38)           
remote:
Finding sources: 100% (38/38)
Receiving objects:   0% (1/806610)
Receiving objects:   1% (8067/806610)
Receiving objects:   2% (16133/806610)
Receiving objects:   3% (24199/806610)
Receiving objects:   4% (32265/806610), 10.18 MiB | 20.35 MiB/s
Receiving
objects:   5% (40331/806610), 10.18 MiB | 20.35 MiB/s
Receiving objects:   6%
(48397/806610), 10.18 MiB | 20.35 MiB/s
Receiving objects:   6% (49045/806610),
10.18 MiB | 20.35 MiB/s
Receiving objects:   7% (56463/806610), 21.73 MiB |
21.73 MiB/s
Receiving objects:   8% (64529/806610), 21.73 MiB | 21.73 MiB/s
Receiving objects:   9% (72595/806610), 21.73 MiB | 21.73 MiB/s
Receiving
objects:  10% (80661/806610), 32.48 MiB | 21.65 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  11%
(88728/806610), 32.48 MiB | 21.65 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  12% (96794/806610),
32.48 MiB | 21.65 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  13% (104860/806610), 32.48 MiB |
21.65 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  13% (105075/806610), 32.48 MiB | 21.65 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  14% (112926/806610), 48.31 MiB | 24.17 MiB/s
Receiving
objects:  15% (120992/806610), 48.31 MiB | 24.17 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  16%
(129058/806610), 48.31 MiB | 24.17 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  17%
(137124/806610), 66.43 MiB | 26.58 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  18%
(145190/806610), 66.43 MiB | 26.58 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  19%
(153256/806610), 66.43 MiB | 26.58 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  19%
(159896/806610), 66.43 MiB | 26.58 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  20%
(161322/806610), 83.43 MiB | 27.82 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  21%
(169389/806610), 83.43 MiB | 27.82 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  22%
(177455/806610), 83.43 MiB | 27.82 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  23%
(185521/806610), 83.43 MiB | 27.82 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  24%
(193587/806610), 101.47 MiB | 29.00 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  25%
(201653/806610), 101.47 MiB | 29.00 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  26%
(209719/806610), 101.47 MiB | 29.00 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  27%
(217785/806610), 101.47 MiB | 29.00 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  27%
(219562/806610), 101.47 MiB | 29.00 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  28%
(225851/806610), 122.18 MiB | 30.55 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  29%
(233917/806610), 122.18 MiB | 30.55 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  30%
(241983/806610), 122.18 MiB | 30.55 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  31%
(250050/806610), 122.18 MiB | 30.55 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  32%
(258116/806610), 122.18 MiB | 30.55 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  33%
(266182/806610), 122.18 MiB | 30.55 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  34%
(274248/806610), 122.18 MiB | 30.55 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  35%
(282314/806610), 122.18 MiB | 30.55 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  36%
(290380/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  37%
(298446/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  38%
(306512/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  39%
(314578/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  40%
(322644/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  41%
(330711/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  42%
(338777/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  43%
(346843/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  44%
(354909/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  45%
(362975/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  46%
(371041/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  47%
(379107/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  48%
(387173/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  49%
(395239/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  50%
(403305/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  51%
(411372/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  52%
(419438/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  52%
(421222/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  53%
(427504/806610), 137.46 MiB | 30.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  54%
(435570/806610), 150.47 MiB | 31.15 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  55%
(443636/806610), 160.89 MiB | 30.90 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  55%
(444613/806610), 160.89 MiB | 30.90 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  56%
(451702/806610), 171.65 MiB | 30.90 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  57%
(459768/806610), 181.79 MiB | 29.64 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  57%
(459851/806610), 181.79 MiB | 29.64 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  57%
(465088/806610), 204.23 MiB | 26.82 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  58%
(467834/806610), 217.07 MiB | 25.67 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  58%
(471120/806610), 228.67 MiB | 23.64 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  59%
(475900/806610), 251.90 MiB | 22.54 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  59%
(476769/806610), 251.90 MiB | 22.54 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  59%
(482388/806610), 275.84 MiB | 23.15 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  60%
(483966/806610), 284.36 MiB | 22.79 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  60%
(488380/806610), 295.33 MiB | 22.85 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  61%
(492033/806610), 320.99 MiB | 23.09 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  61%
(494842/806610), 320.99 MiB | 23.09 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  62%
(500099/806610), 345.68 MiB | 23.37 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  62%
(502447/806610), 345.68 MiB | 23.37 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  63%
(508165/806610), 369.49 MiB | 23.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  63%
(508340/806610), 369.49 MiB | 23.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  63%
(515700/806610), 394.58 MiB | 24.49 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  64%
(516231/806610), 405.08 MiB | 24.39 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  64%
(524205/806610), 417.50 MiB | 24.35 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  65%
(524297/806610), 417.50 MiB | 24.35 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  66%
(532363/806610), 442.39 MiB | 24.23 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  66%
(532452/806610), 442.39 MiB | 24.23 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  66%
(540228/806610), 469.93 MiB | 24.90 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  67%
(540429/806610), 469.93 MiB | 24.90 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  67%
(546936/806610), 496.55 MiB | 25.57 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  68%
(548495/806610), 508.55 MiB | 25.33 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  68%
(553835/806610), 522.43 MiB | 26.08 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  69%
(556561/806610), 546.91 MiB | 26.00 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  69%
(558983/806610), 546.91 MiB | 26.00 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  70%
(564627/806610), 573.57 MiB | 25.97 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  70%
(564643/806610), 573.57 MiB | 25.97 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  70%
(571963/806610), 599.12 MiB | 25.72 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  71%
(572694/806610), 612.16 MiB | 25.70 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  71%
(579737/806610), 625.82 MiB | 26.06 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  72%
(580760/806610), 638.73 MiB | 25.84 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  72%
(584921/806610), 649.36 MiB | 25.58 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  73%
(588826/806610), 668.74 MiB | 24.09 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  73%
(589490/806610), 668.74 MiB | 24.09 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  73%
(592259/806610), 687.90 MiB | 22.62 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  74%
(596892/806610), 697.41 MiB | 21.84 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  74%
(598795/806610), 708.29 MiB | 21.36 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  75%
(604958/806610), 727.52 MiB | 19.73 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  75%
(609014/806610), 727.52 MiB | 19.73 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  76%
(613024/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  77%
(621090/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  78%
(629156/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  79%
(637222/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  80%
(645288/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  81%
(653355/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  82%
(661421/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  83%
(669487/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  84%
(677553/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  85%
(685619/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  86%
(693685/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  87%
(701751/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  88%
(709817/806610), 737.40 MiB | 19.56 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  89%
(717883/806610), 753.10 MiB | 21.03 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  90%
(725949/806610), 753.10 MiB | 21.03 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  91%
(734016/806610), 753.10 MiB | 21.03 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  92%
(742082/806610), 753.10 MiB | 21.03 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  93%
(750148/806610), 753.10 MiB | 21.03 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  94%
(758214/806610), 753.10 MiB | 21.03 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  94%
(760146/806610), 753.10 MiB | 21.03 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  95%
(766280/806610), 767.77 MiB | 22.01 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  96%
(774346/806610), 767.77 MiB | 22.01 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  97%
(782412/806610), 767.77 MiB | 22.01 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  98%
(790478/806610), 767.77 MiB | 22.01 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  99%
(798544/806610), 767.77 MiB | 22.01 MiB/s
remote: Total 806610 (delta 650490),
reused 806597 (delta 650490)
Receiving objects: 100% (806610/806610), 767.77 MiB | 22.01 MiB/s
Receiving
objects: 100% (806610/806610), 777.03 MiB | 24.82 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:   0% (0/650490)
Resolving deltas:   1% (6505/650490)
Resolving
deltas:   2% (13010/650490)
Resolving deltas:   3% (19515/650490)
Resolving
deltas:   4% (26020/650490)
Resolving deltas:   5% (32525/650490)
Resolving
deltas:   6% (39030/650490)
Resolving deltas:   7% (45535/650490)
Resolving
deltas:   8% (52040/650490)
Resolving deltas:   8% (54023/650490)
Resolving
deltas:   9% (58545/650490)
Resolving deltas:  10% (65049/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  11% (71554/650490)
Resolving deltas:  12% (78059/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  12% (80547/650490)
Resolving deltas:  13% (84564/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  14% (91069/650490)
Resolving deltas:  15% (97574/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  16% (104079/650490)
Resolving deltas:  17% (110584/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  18% (117089/650490)
Resolving deltas:  19% (123594/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  19% (129563/650490)
Resolving deltas:  20% (130098/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  21% (136603/650490)
Resolving deltas:  22% (143108/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  23% (149613/650490)
Resolving deltas:  24% (156118/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  25% (162623/650490)
Resolving deltas:  26% (169128/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  26% (169669/650490)
Resolving deltas:  27% (175633/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  28% (182138/650490)
Resolving deltas:  29% (188643/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  30% (195147/650490)
Resolving deltas:  31% (201652/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  32% (208157/650490)
Resolving deltas:  33% (214662/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  34% (221167/650490)
Resolving deltas:  35% (227672/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  36% (234177/650490)
Resolving deltas:  37% (240682/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  37% (245257/650490)
Resolving deltas:  38% (247187/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  39% (253692/650490)
Resolving deltas:  40% (260196/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  41% (266701/650490)
Resolving deltas:  42% (273206/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  43% (279711/650490)
Resolving deltas:  44% (286216/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  45% (292721/650490)
Resolving deltas:  45% (295348/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  46% (299226/650490)
Resolving deltas:  47% (305731/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  48% (312236/650490)
Resolving deltas:  49% (318741/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  50% (325245/650490)
Resolving deltas:  51% (331750/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  51% (337204/650490)
Resolving deltas:  52% (338255/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  53% (344760/650490)
Resolving deltas:  53% (345131/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  53% (349618/650490)
Resolving deltas:  54% (351265/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  54% (355167/650490)
Resolving deltas:  55% (357770/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  55% (361674/650490)
Resolving deltas:  56% (364275/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  56% (368428/650490)
Resolving deltas:  57% (370780/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  57% (372062/650490)
Resolving deltas:  57% (373250/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  57% (374571/650490)
Resolving deltas:  58% (377285/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  58% (377414/650490)
Resolving deltas:  59% (383790/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  59% (389126/650490)
Resolving deltas:  60% (390294/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  61% (396799/650490)
Resolving deltas:  62% (403304/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  62% (408552/650490)
Resolving deltas:  63% (409809/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  64% (416314/650490)
Resolving deltas:  64% (416724/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  65% (422819/650490)
Resolving deltas:  65% (422953/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  65% (424227/650490)
Resolving deltas:  65% (424800/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  65% (425447/650490)
Resolving deltas:  65% (427050/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  66% (429324/650490)
Resolving deltas:  66% (432457/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  67% (435829/650490)
Resolving deltas:  67% (439483/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  67% (441258/650490)
Resolving deltas:  67% (441605/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  67% (441965/650490)
Resolving deltas:  68% (442334/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  68% (442339/650490)
Resolving deltas:  68% (442727/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  68% (443124/650490)
Resolving deltas:  68% (443538/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  68% (443952/650490)
Resolving deltas:  68% (444384/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  68% (444832/650490)
Resolving deltas:  68% (445306/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  68% (445811/650490)
Resolving deltas:  68% (446347/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  69% (448839/650490)
Resolving deltas:  69% (452594/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  70% (455343/650490)
Resolving deltas:  70% (457709/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  71% (461848/650490)
Resolving deltas:  71% (463195/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  71% (467863/650490)
Resolving deltas:  72% (468353/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  73% (474858/650490)
Resolving deltas:  73% (475812/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  74% (481363/650490)
Resolving deltas:  74% (482138/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  75% (487868/650490)
Resolving deltas:  75% (488741/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  76% (494373/650490)
Resolving deltas:  76% (494890/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  76% (500342/650490)
Resolving deltas:  77% (500878/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  78% (507383/650490)
Resolving deltas:  78% (507505/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  78% (511559/650490)
Resolving deltas:  79% (513888/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  79% (518262/650490)
Resolving deltas:  80% (520392/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  81% (526897/650490)
Resolving deltas:  81% (528295/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  82% (533402/650490)
Resolving deltas:  82% (535696/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  83% (539907/650490)
Resolving deltas:  83% (542594/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  84% (546412/650490)
Resolving deltas:  84% (547102/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  84% (548527/650490)
Resolving deltas:  84% (549571/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  84% (550455/650490)
Resolving deltas:  84% (551217/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  84% (551916/650490)
Resolving deltas:  85% (552917/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  85% (553610/650490)
Resolving deltas:  86% (559422/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  86% (559927/650490)
Resolving deltas:  86% (565509/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  87% (565927/650490)
Resolving deltas:  87% (569272/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  87% (571315/650490)
Resolving deltas:  88% (572432/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  88% (574885/650490)
Resolving deltas:  89% (578937/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  89% (582307/650490)
Resolving deltas:  90% (585441/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  90% (586843/650490)
Resolving deltas:  90% (590983/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  90% (591772/650490)
Resolving deltas:  91% (591946/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  91% (594285/650490)
Resolving deltas:  91% (598153/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  92% (598451/650490)
Resolving deltas:  92% (600602/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  92% (604791/650490)
Resolving deltas:  93% (604956/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  93% (608723/650490)
Resolving deltas:  94% (611461/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  94% (613848/650490)
Resolving deltas:  95% (617966/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  95% (620653/650490)
Resolving deltas:  95% (622468/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  95% (624007/650490)
Resolving deltas:  96% (624471/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  96% (625026/650490)
Resolving deltas:  96% (629694/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  97% (630976/650490)
Resolving deltas:  97% (634891/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  98% (637481/650490)
Resolving deltas:  98% (638946/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  99% (643986/650490)
Resolving deltas:  99% (644038/650490)
Resolving
deltas:  99% (646997/650490)
Resolving deltas: 100% (650490/650490)
Resolving
deltas: 100% (650490/650490), done.
[0:02:45] Still working on:
[0:02:45]   v8
________ running 'vpython third_party/depot_tools/update_depot_tools_toggle.py
--disable' in
'/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor'
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor/depot_tools/.cipd_bin/.cipd/pkgs/0/fI6WggdkRyN1r91MnTeApc2_gyTtXfYpueHZVLcaF8gC/vpython:
could not resolve options: failed to resolve Python script: stat
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor/third_party/depot_tools/update_depot_tools_toggle.py:
no such file or directory
Error: Command 'vpython third_party/depot_tools/update_depot_tools_toggle.py
--disable' returned non-zero exit status 1 in
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor
Running: gclient root
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "name": "v8",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "managed": False,
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads
Subprocess failed with return code 2.
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/builder.rb:83:in
`block in setup_build_deps!': unable to fetch v8 source (RuntimeError)
from
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/builder.rb:81:in
`chdir'
from
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/builder.rb:81:in
`setup_build_deps!'
from
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in
`build_libv8!'
from
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in
`install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0
for inspection.
Results logged to
/home/runner/work/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/libv8-8.4.255.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing libv8 (8.4.255.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '8.4.255.0' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer was resolved to 0.3.1, which depends on
    libv8
Error: Process completed with exit code 5.
```

Comment: Whatever `vpython` is is not working. Grep your source trees to figure out what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by https://github.com/rubyjs/libv8/issues/310 and caused by upgrade from Bundler v2.1.x to v2.2.x Sorry, I don't have a simple fix for you. Maybe downgrade to Bundler 2.1.x for now?